# Similarity of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, eigenvalues

Consider the matrix, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ .

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} i \lambda & -1 & i & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\ i  & 0 & - i \lambda & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I would like to know if there exists a matrix $B$, independent of $\lambda$ such that

$$ B A B^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} K_1(\lambda) & 0\\0 &K_2(\lambda) \end{pmatrix}$$

where $K_1,K_2$ are two $2 \times 2$ block matrices.

The reason I believe this to be true is that the eigenvalues of $A$ seem to decouple. This is what suggests this block form.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by eigenvalues which "decouple", it's a string of four numbers, their product is 1, but why "decouple" ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker they seem to be solutions to a second order polynomial.

Comment: hmm, the four eigenvalues are two complex conjugate pairs, I'm not sure why that would imply the block diagonalization.

Comment: @PritamBemis Have you looked at joint block diagonalization algorithms? I would think that these could let you figure out an analytical result. E.g., see https://github.com/Prof-Boualem-Boashash/MTFSP_Software_package/blob/master/MTFSP%20V1.1/Supporting%20functions/BSS/JointBlockDiag.m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show that it is not possible for $\phi=\pi/2$, so it is certainly not for general $\phi$. (actually, I don't think that it is possible for any single $\phi$ except $0$ and $\pi$, by an analogous argument).

I will multiply $A$ by $-i$ and conjugate it by
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i \end{pmatrix}$ just to have real coefficients for simplicity, it clearly doesn't affect block-diagonalisabilty. $A$ then becomes:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -\lambda & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and has characteristic polynomial $X^4-(\lambda^2+3)X^2+1$. If it was block diagonalizable, then the characteristic polynomial (seen as a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}[\lambda]$) would factor as a product of two factors of degree $2$ in $X$:
$$X^4-(\lambda^2+3)X^2+1=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+cX+d)$$
with $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}[\lambda]$. Comparing coefficients yields:

- $bd=1$ (in particular $b,d\in \mathbb{C}$)
- $a+c=0$
- $ad+bc=a(d-b)=0$, so either $a=0$ or $b=d=\pm 1$

The case $a=0$ is impossible since then the factors would have coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ and we couldn't get the coefficient $\lambda^2+3$. Hence the factorization must have the form
$$X^4-(\lambda^2+3)X^2+1=(X^2+aX\pm 1)(X^2-aX\pm 1)$$
Comparing coefficients of $X^2$, we have
$$-a^2\pm2=-(\lambda^2+3)$$
$$a^2\pm2=\lambda^2+3$$
$$a^2=\lambda^2+1 \ \text{or}\ a^2=\lambda^2+5$$
Since neither of $\lambda^2+1$ and $\lambda^2+5$ are squares in $\mathbb{C}[\lambda]$, we get a contradiction.

Comment: interesting, let me go in detail through your answer. but somehow i am surprised about this negative answer, as I saw you answered another similar question, where you showed that eigenvalues always come in pairs, just as here and obtained a block reduction. In fact, just as in the other answer, I now also checked that the degenerate eigenvalues are stable under taking products of such matrices for different $\lambda$ but fixed $\varphi$. Strange, don't you think?

Comment: I should add that actually I only asked this question trying to generalize what you did in the other post, but somehow it does not work, as you proved yourself. However, the result still seems to apply.

Comment: What do you mean by "the degenerate eigenvalues are stable under taking products of such matrices for different $\lambda$"?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Call the matrix I defined $A(\lambda,\alpha)$. Let $\lambda_i$ be a sequence of real numbers, then $\prod_{i=1}^n A(\lambda_i,\alpha)$ has two double degenerate/complex conjugate eigenvalues. This is precisely what happened also in this other post. But apparently, this time it is not because of some block-diagonal form?

Comment: The matrices do not have degenerate eigenvalues in general, actually for $\phi=\pi/2$ the matrix $A$ has 4 distinct eigenvalues for any $\lambda$.

Comment: sorry, degenerate or complex conjugate pairs. I corrected it after I wrote it the first time. But nevertheless, what I mean is, it is just the same as with the $\mu$ in the other post.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what explains this phenomenon this time (in the case $\phi=\pi/2$ it follows directly from skew-hermiticity but that doesn't work for general $\phi$)

Comment: I see that for $\phi=\pi/2$ the matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric. How do you conclude from this that the product of such matrices has complex conjugate pairs as eigenvalues? (the only question is really why one complex conjugate pair exists, I understand how to show that there are two then in that case)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124677/discussion-between-antoine-labelle-and-pritam-bemis).

Comment: actually, I do have a stupid question. I mean after all, the matrix is diagonalizable since we know what its distinct eigenvalues are, no? So how is it possible that you show it cannot be block-diagonalized, which seems like a weaker question?

Comment: The matrix for a fixed $\lambda$ is diagonalizable, but there is no base that simultaneously (block-)diagonalize all $A(\lambda)$